# No me quiere mostrar los datos sin embargo si me los agrega

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

El siguiente es mi archivo de mostrar

```
<?php
    include "conectar.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Panel de Administración</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  href="./js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="./imagenes/logo.png" id="logo">
        <a href="./carritodecompras.php" title="ver carrito de compras">
            <img src="./imagenes/carrito.png">
        </a>
    </header>
    <section>
    <nav class="menu2">
      <menu>
        <li><a href="./">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="selected">Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Agregar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Salir</a></li>
      </menu>
    </nav>

    <center><h1>Últimas Compras</h1></center>
    <table border="1px" width="100%">   
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Clave</td>
            <td>Fecha de pedido</td>
            <td>Productos</td>
            <td>Precio</td>
            <td>Cantidad</td>
            <td>Cliente</td>
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>   

        <?php
            $consulta=$Conexion->prepare("SELECT Id_pedido, Numeroventa, Fecha_pedido, Descripcion, Precio, cantidad, NOMBRE, Total from Pedido JOIN Productos JOIN Usuarios WHERE Pedido.Id_producto=Productos.Id_producto AND Pedido.Id_usuario=Usuarios.Id_usuario");
            $consulta->execute();
            $resultado = $consulta->fetchALL();
            $numeroventa=0;
            foreach ($resultado as $f) {
                    if($numeroventa !=$f['Numeroventa']){
                        echo '<tr><td>Compra Número: '.$f['Numeroventa'].' </td></tr>';
                    }
                    $numeroventa=$f['Numeroventa'];
                    echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$f['Id_pedido'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$f['Fecha_pedido'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$f['Descripcion'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$f['Precio'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$f['cantidad'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$f['NOMBRE'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$f['Total'].'</td>

                    </tr>';
            }
        ?>
    </table>
    </tbody>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

En la consola me aparece **Column 'Precio' in field list is ambiguous** pero no se porque si mis campos todos se llaman igual y mis tablas tambien tienen el nombre correcto.

El campo Descripcion es de la tabla Productos y el campo NOMBRE de la tabla Usuarios por eso estoy haciendo un join pero si le pongo Productos.Descripcion me sigue apareciendo lo mismo y si le pongo a todos el nombredelatabla.campo tampoco aparece nada.

Comment: Tienes certeza sobre la sintaxis de esos JOIN? No hay un `USING` para indicar qué columna usar en el join. Y si varias de las tablas tienen el campo `Precio`, te va a pedir que especifiques **cuál** usar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba cambiando tu consulta a esta forma:

```
SELECT Id_pedido, Numeroventa, Fecha_pedido, Descripcion, pedido.Precio, cantidad, NOMBRE, Total from Pedido JOIN Productos JOIN Usuarios WHERE Pedido.Id_producto=Productos.Id_producto AND Pedido.Id_usuario=Usuarios.Id_usuario
```

Todo parece indicar que la columna "Precio" la tienes tanto en "Pedido" como en "Productos", eso está haciendo que al momento de lanzar la query MySql no sepa cual de las dos tomar. Especificando la tabla puedes solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Al especificar una tabla, ya sea en `FROM` o `JOIN`, puedes agregar un alias para facilitar la selección de columnas; en este caso, `p` para pedidos y `prod` para productos.

Ejemplos:

```
# Alias de tabla con la palabra "as"
FROM pedidos as ped
# Alias sin la palabra "as"
FOM productos prod
```

Lo recomendable es que siempre agregues un prefijo con el nombre o alias de la tabla a cada columna, no importa si es única o se repite en otras tablas; te ayuda a saber el origen de los datos y facilita el mantenimiento.

Como puedes ver, es más fácil crear un alias corto para usar como prefijo en lugar del nombre de la tabla.

```
SELECT p.Id_pedido, p.Numeroventa, p.Fecha_pedido, p.cantidad, p.Precio, p.Total,
    prod.Descripcion,
    u.NOMBRE
FROM Pedido p
JOIN Productos prod
    ON p.Id_producto = prod.Id_producto
JOIN Usuarios u
    ON p.Id_usuario = u.Id_usuario
```

Lo más adecuado es aplicar las condiciones en `JOIN` para que la consulta sea más específica y dejar el filtro `WHERE` para la tabla principal, por ejemplo, si deseas obtener solo los pedidos que se hayan realizado dentro de un rango de fechas.